# active class issue

Tags: javascript

I've set an *active* class for the current link and it works well if the href is like " gallery.htm " or a proper web page. But after I changed the layout I preferred to set an ID for each link destination so that user is directed to the destination in the same page only rather than being switched between pages.

I suppose the problem is too simple that I just could not find anything related on google. Anyway don't mind please;I'm not good in javascript yet.

Now the problem is the active class CAN NOT be set using this script.

```
var url = window.location.pathname,
    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$");
$('a').each(function () {
    if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) {
        $(this).addClass('active1st');
    }
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/R65Gd/1/) is the sample.

So anything wrong somewhere?

Comment: My mistake; I just corrected that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no element or set of elements matching the path `'#Menu div span #Menu1st a'`.

Your identifiers are `a` and `b`, and nowhere does `Menu` or `Menu1st` appear.

EDIT:

Now with your update, your identifiers `a` and `b` are `div` elements, not `a` (link) elements; you're also not specifying in your selector that `a` is an identifier, and you're just trying to apply it to all `a` *elements*. If you put a hash in front of that in the selector, such that the selector is `#a`, then it will execute for *that* element with *that* identifier, but as I said, that's not a link and doesn't have an `href`, therefore `this.href.replace` will break; and, even if it *was* a link and the logic *would* execute, then it would *still* be broken because of your typos of the class being applied (as in, it doesn't exist in your stylesheet!).

There are a number of issues summed up above. I'm not sure people need to tell them this stuff, just pay attention - or take a break for 10 minutes if you've been staring at something like this for too long.

Comment: But is that not OK for a sample ? because I could simply give different IDs to both a elements. Did I get what u meant?

Comment: in the 3rd line of my scripts I mean the a element NOT a#. And thank you for going through details

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but I also think it's a selector problem.

Please correct me if i'm wrong but several id selectors causing always problems.

Without knowing your full html I guess this will work:

```
$(#Menu1st a')
```